How to create GIST index with the correct predicate
The PostGIS guide say that we must to use a GIST index, and the PostgreSQL guide say that we can use a WHERE predicate:
CREATE INDEX mytable_geom_idx ON t USING GIST (geom) WHERE predicate;

But the predicate to be optimized involves two variables and a function, how to express it at INDEX clause?
WHERE pt_geom && cell_geom AND (is_not_shared OR ST_Intersects(pt_geom,cell_geom))

Is possible to add something at WHERE predicate to do a better indexation in the OR operation? The pt_geom is a constant, and the table has  ~50% of the  cell_geom with is_not_shared=true. The function ST_Intersects is immutable.

Notes
The suggestion of @JGH is to show here the explain of the real query... At this moment I have only a similar table, with index gist (geom).
This is the result, in a point with is_contained=true.
explain (buffers, analyze) with p AS (SELECT ST_transform(ST_Point(-45.697189,-22.686177,4326),952019) AS pt_geom) select isolabel_ext, cindex, is_contained  from p, osmc.coverage t where not(t.is_country) AND NOT(t.is_overlay) and   t.geom && p.pt_geom AND (t.is_contained OR ST_Intersects(t.geom,p.pt_geom));

--------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using osm_coverage_geom_idx1 on coverage t  (cost=0.28..20.80 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.103..0.136 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (geom && '0101000020D3860E0031AE1200C355564122919D4092C56041'::geometry)
   Filter: ((NOT is_country) AND (NOT is_overlay) AND (is_contained OR st_intersects(geom, '0101000020D3860E0031AE1200C355564122919D4092C56041'::geometry)))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   Buffers: shared hit=10

Same query in a point (-45.678648,-22.578077) with is_contained=false.
------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using osm_coverage_geom_idx1 on coverage t  (cost=0.28..20.80 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.083..0.140 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (geom && '0101000020D3860E00644B8CFFF8575641002995C05FCB6041'::geometry)
   Filter: ((NOT is_country) AND (NOT is_overlay) AND (is_contained OR st_intersects(geom, '0101000020D3860E00644B8CFFF8575641002995C05FCB6041'::geometry)))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 3
   Buffers: shared hit=11


It is a server with some use, after few minutes, change the behaviour:
 Index Scan using osm_coverage_geom_idx1 on coverage t  (cost=0.28..20.80 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.317..0.388 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (geom && '0101000020D3860E0031AE1200C355564122919D4092C56041'::geometry)
   Filter: ((NOT is_country) AND (NOT is_overlay) AND (is_contained OR st_intersects(geom, '0101000020D3860E0031AE1200C355564122919D4092C56041'::geometry)))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   Buffers: shared hit=34
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=358

Repeating result:
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   Buffers: shared hit=10

Removing the OR (WHERE ... and   t.geom && p.pt_geom AND ST_Intersects(t.geom,p.pt_geom)) result:
 Index Scan using osm_coverage_geom_idx1 on coverage t  (cost=0.28..20.80 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.113..0.146 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((geom && '0101000020D3860E0031AE1200C355564122919D4092C56041'::geometry) AND (geom && '0101000020D3860E0031AE1200C355564122919D4092C56041'::geometry))
   Filter: ((NOT is_country) AND (NOT is_overlay) AND st_intersects(geom, '0101000020D3860E0031AE1200C355564122919D4092C56041'::geometry))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   Buffers: shared hit=10
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=5 read=1

After repeat:
 Index Scan using osm_coverage_geom_idx1 on coverage t  (cost=0.28..20.80 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.206..0.272 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((geom && '0101000020D3860E0031AE1200C355564122919D4092C56041'::geometry) AND (geom && '0101000020D3860E0031AE1200C355564122919D4092C56041'::geometry))
   Filter: ((NOT is_country) AND (NOT is_overlay) AND st_intersects(geom, '0101000020D3860E0031AE1200C355564122919D4092C56041'::geometry))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   Buffers: shared hit=10


 && cell_geom --> it mean that you need the spatial index on every rows. Also, since the partial index predicate can't use any external information, such as pt_geom here, because of the or, you still need an index on the entire table.

That doesn't mean than the entire query can't be optimized, but for that you would have to post the entire query and the result of the explain (buffers, analyze) of the query

actual time=0.103..0.136  --> what are you trying to optimize? all queries you have posted run under less than a millisecond. Rows Removed by Filter: 1 -> making a partial index will not bring much, the spatial index on the entire table is already doing almost all the job.
